# Disable all options from a chosen multiselect dropdown when a particular option is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu, jquery-chosen

```
<script>
    function disableSelectedValues() {
        var cssOptions = [];
        $(".input_field.criteria_countries option").removeAttr("disabled");
        $.each($(".input_field.criteria_countries"), function(index, select) {
            cssOptions = [];
            var values = $(select).val();
            if (values) {
                for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
                    cssOptions.push("option[value=" + values[i] + "]");
                }
            }

            if (cssOptions.length) {
                console.log(".input_field.criteria_countries " + cssOptions.join(",.input_field.criteria_countries "));
                // disable all options with the selected values
                $(".input_field.criteria_countries " + cssOptions.join(",.input_field.criteria_countries ")).attr("disabled", true);

                // enable all options with the selected values for the current select
                $(select).find(cssOptions.join()).removeAttr("disabled");
            }
        });
    }

    function add_mitigator() {
        var option = '';
        var delete_pop_up = '';

        var tot_risk = $("#total_risk").val();
        var max_risk = $("#max_risk_id").val();
        var increased_risk = parseInt(parseInt(max_risk) + 1);
        var total_risk = parseInt(parseInt(tot_risk) + 1);

        for (i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
            option += "<option value=" + i + ">" + i + "</option>";
        }

        var risk_div = $("<div id='risk_" + increased_risk + "' style='margin-top: 5px;'></div>");

        var risk_drp_cont = $("<div id='risk_drp_cont" + increased_risk + "' style='float:left; width:302px; position:relative;'></div>");
        var risk_drop = $('<select />', {
            'id': 'risk_mitigator_offer_' + increased_risk,
                'name': 'risk_mitigator_offer[]',
                'class': 'input_field criteria_countries',
                'multiple': true,
                'style': 'width:202px;'
        });

        $(risk_drop).append(option);
        $(risk_drp_cont).append(risk_drop);

        $("#total_risk").val(total_risk);
        $("#max_risk_id").val(increased_risk);

        var risk_wgt_cont = $("<div id='risk_wgt_cont" + increased_risk + "' style='float:left;width:45px; position:relative; margin-left:5px;'></div>");
        var risk_weight = $('<input />', {
            'id': 'risk_weight_' + increased_risk,
                'name': 'risk_weight[]',
                'type': 'text',
                'class': 'input_field',
                'style': 'color:#777777; width: 40px; mergin-left: 30px;'
        });
        $(risk_wgt_cont).append(risk_weight);
        $(risk_weight).val('0');

        $(risk_div).append(risk_drp_cont).append(risk_wgt_cont);
        $(risk_drop).chosen({
            no_results_text: "Oops, nothing found!"
        }).change(function() {
            disableSelectedValues();
            $(".input_field.criteria_countries").trigger("chosen:updated");
        });

        var clear_div = $("<div style='clear: both;'></div>");
        $("#mitigator_container").append(risk_div).append(clear_div);
        $("#risk_mitigator_offer_" + increased_risk + "_chosen").css({
            "width": "100%",
                "height": "30px",
                "border-radius": "2px"
        });

        disableSelectedValues();
        $(".input_field.criteria_countries").trigger("chosen:updated");
    }
</script>
<input id="total_risk" name="total_risk" type="text" value="1" />
<input id="max_risk_id" name="max_risk_i" type="text" value="1" />
<a class="btn blue_button" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="add_mitigator();">Add Mitigator</a>

<div id="mitigator_container" style="height:auto;">
    <div id="risk_1">
        <div id="risk_drp_cont_1" style="float:left;">
            <select id="risk_mitigator_offer_1" name="risk_mitigator_offer[]" class="input_field criteria_countries" style="width:302px;" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="All">All</option>
                <option value="1">1</option>
                <option value="2">2</option>
                <option value="3">3</option>
                <option value="4">4</option>
                <option value="5">5</option>
                <option value="6">6</option>
                <option value="7">7</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div id="risk_wgt_cont_1" style="float:left;width:45px; position:relative; margin-left:5px;">
            <input id="risk_weight_1" name="risk_weight[]" class="input_field" type="text" value="0" style="color:#777777; width: 40px;" maxlength="3" />
        </div>
        <div id="risk_del_cont_1" style="float:left; width:20px; position:relative; margin-top:5px"> <a onclick="" href="javascript:void(0);" id="delete_mitigator"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash trash"></span></a>

        </div>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both"></div>
</div>
```

[Example Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p0b4j5o8/26/)

Description of Requirement:

1. I have a **multi-select dropdown** using **chosen** plugin.
2. The first option is "**All**"
3. Those who are accustomed with **chosen** dropdown,they know that when an option is selected(from **chosen multiselect**) and presented in the **dropdown textarea**-like field, you will see it **disabled** from the **list menu** automatically.
4. I want that, when the first option "**All**" will be selected, then all the other options from the list menu will be also **disabled**.
5. When the "**All**" option will be removed from the **dropdown textarea**-like field(deleting by clicking on the **cross** with the selected option), then again all the options will be **enabled**.

Answer (score 4):

### Answer

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.chosen-select').chosen({});

    $('.chosen-select').on('change', function(evt, params) {
       var $s = $(this);

        if (params.selected && params.selected == "Any") 
        {
            // disable the select
            $s.children('option').not(':selected').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('disabled','disabled');
            });
        }
        else if (params.deselected && params.deselected == "Any") 
        {
            // enable back
            $s.children('option').each(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
            });
        }
        // force chosen update
        $('.chosen-select').trigger('chosen:updated');
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#foobar").chosen().on('chosen:showing_dropdown',function() {
            $('.chosen-select').attr('disabled', true).trigger('chosen:updated');
            $('.chosen-select').attr('disabled', false).trigger('chosen:updated');
            $('.search-choice-close').hide();
    });
    $('.search-choice-close').hide();
});
```